# Set organization wide email in scratch org?

Tags: email, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

When trying to deploy an auto responder rule to a new scratch org, we're getting:

> [email] is an invalid From email address.: Email Address

Is there a scratch org config to set an organization wide email? Surprisingly I haven't found any resources about this specific question.